# Debug an app on a device without any USB port?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

I have a android device that doesn't have a usb data transfer and i need to debug an android app on it. all the solution that i already read, need to connect the device using usb cable at least once. I was wondering is there anyway that i can debug an android app without any need of usb cable?

And please dont say `Adb via Wi-Fi` because it needs usb connection to setup it.

And i also can't root my device!

Comment: root your device and use WIFI ADB app

Comment: then there is no way.

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to sumarize. If you are rooted, just install any "adb over wifi" app form Google Play, it will allow to enable adb over wi-fi without connecting to usb.

If you are not rooted, debug is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Adb via Wi-Fi. You will need IP address of the device and your device and machine should be on same Wi-Fi network

There are apps available for same in google play store as well, most of the time they need device to be rooted

Comment: told you i cant connect my device using usb and adb need usb connection to setup it!

Comment: If your device is rooted connection is not needed